# DatagridView New row Add Error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to add new row in Datagrid but have error.

**ERROR: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.**

```
     row = new string[] { "0", "1", hesab_nomresi,soyad,ad,ataadi,vesiqe,teskilat_kodu,tevellud,nomre,cins };
     kartsifarishiGridView.Rows.Add(elaveEtme.row);

     AllowUserToAddRow = false;
```

**Datasource:** (*added from comment of author*)

```
string sqlSorgu = "SELECT" + " customer.id, + " IIf (customer.cins = 'M','Kişi','Qadın') AS Cins " + " FROM customer ORDER BY customer.id ASC";
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSorgu, Program.esas.bazayaQosul); 
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 
set = new DataSet(); 
set.Tables.Add(dataTable); 
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

kartsifarishiGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Comment: ERROR : Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Comment: What is a data source? Is it collection or DataTalbe? Please provide the piece of code where you are performing binding.

Answer (score 2):

You can add new row directly to the data source which you are binding to the grid and call kartsifarishiGridView.DataBind();

```
new string[] { "0", "1", hesab_nomresi,soyad,ad,ataadi,vesiqe,teskilat_kodu,tevellud,nomre,cins };
```

The idea is that you can't add a row to a binded datagridview. You'll have to add it to the structure that the datagridview is binded to (the datatable).

**Example:**

```
       string sqlSorgu = "SELECT" + " customer.id," + " IIf (customer.cins = 'M','Kişi','Qadın') AS Cins " + " FROM customer ORDER BY customer.id ASC"; 

        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSorgu, Program.esas.bazayaQosul); 
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 
        set = new DataSet(); 
        set.Tables.Add(dataTable); 
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        //  Here is the code for adding new row
        dataTable.Rows.Add(new string[]
                               {
                                   "0", "1", hesab_nomresi, soyad, ad, ataadi, vesiqe, teskilat_kodu, tevellud, nomre,
                                   cins
                               });

        kartsifarishiGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   :(

Comment: Just don't use DataBind method. I thought it is ASP.NET GridView :)

Comment: MY SQL query          string sqlSorgu = "SELECT" +
               " customer.id, +
                " IIf (customer.cins = 'M','Kişi','Qadın') AS Cins " +
                    " FROM customer  ORDER BY customer.id ASC";
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSorgu, Program.esas.bazayaQosul);
       DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                set = new DataSet();
                set.Tables.Add(dataTable);
            
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                kartsifarishiGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to tackle this a generic way:

```
myDataGridView.BindingContext[dg.DataSource, dg.DataMember].AddNew();
```